# D3.js Modifying DOM in update phase

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to do something like collapsible list in D3.js. Let's say we have data with a format `data = [{"title": "lorem", "items": ["lorem", "ipsum",  "..."], "state": "collapsed"}]`

Now I want to render this data as a group of svg text tags when state is not 'collapsed and render only one text tag with title otherwise.

```html
<g class="item">
<text>Title</text>
<text>Item 1</text>
<text>Item 2</text>
</g>
<g class="item collapsed">
<text> Title2</text>
</g>
```

My problem is that when user clicks a list item it should fold/unfold appropriately but the underlying datum is not changed so I am not in enter selection and I cannot use append to generate tags for items. How could I solve it? Or maybe I should use JQuery to perform DOM manipulation if a change is not directly mapped to a data?

Comment: Which version of D3js are you using?

Comment: v5.9.2 (latest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually understood what was wrong. In my code after merging enter and update selections I call transition to move nodes in proper places. Transition doesn't return `selection` but it's own object `transition` which has very similar interfaces to `selection` but lacks `append` and `data` and few other methods. So solution was just to wrap transition in call method so I still operate on selection and now I can use `apppend` and `data` as usual.

So my code looked like this:

```
const nodeUpdate = node // nodeUpdate is now a transition object!!!
    .merge(nodeEnter)
    .transition(transition)
    .attr('transform', d => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`);
```

And now it is:

```
const nodeUpdate = node // nodeUpdate is a selection
    .merge(nodeEnter)
    .call(s => s.transition(transition).attr('transform', d => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`));
```